# Determining $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n} e^{-x^{3}-x} d x$

Tags: integration, limits

I have tried to solve this using similar methods of this question but the problem is that I have $\exp(-x^{3}-x)$ and I am stuck at this part.

Comment: Hint: dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It holds that $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n e^{-x^3-x} \to e^{-x^3}$ monotonically. Thus there holds that

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^\infty (1+\frac{x}{n})^ne^{-x^3-x} d x &= \int_0^\infty e^{-x^3} dx =  \Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)
\end{align*}

with the Gamma function. The last equality can be seen with the substitution $x^3 = t$ and using partial integration and the substitution rule

\begin{align*}
\Gamma(\frac{4}{3}) &= \int_0^\infty t^{\frac{4}{3}-1}e^{-t}dt = \int_0^\infty t^\frac{1}{3}e^{-t}dt = \int_0^\infty x e^{-x^3} 3 x^2 dx = 3\int_0^\infty x (x^2 e^{-x^3}) dx\\
&=3\left(\left[ x \frac{e^{-x^3}}{-3}\right]^\infty_0 - \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x^3}}{-3} dx\right) = \int_0^\infty e^{-x^3}dx 
\end{align*}